# Failed building wheel for pillow

Tags: python-2.7, word-cloud

Trying to build a wordcloud in python.

```
# Start with loading all necessary libraries

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud
```

pandas imported just fine, although took a bit longer then expected.
now i tried importing `matplotlib.pyplot` using  `sudo pip3 install matplotlib` and received this error response

```text
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/ec/3d77b10ac3d30590f5431fd2dc59c58d20c020af107b47f8974896afc5c9/matplotlib-3.4.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (1.21.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.7)
Collecting pillow>=6.2.0 (from matplotlib)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/2a/2fc11b54e2742db06297f7fa7f420a0e3069fdcf0e4b57dfec33f0b08622/Pillow-8.4.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (1.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib) (1.12.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: pillow
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pillow ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-8v6p9cen/pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-vqicltkx --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  running egg_info
  writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching '*.c'
  warning: no files found matching '*.h'
  warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
  writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext
  
  
  The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
  
  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/pip-install-8v6p9cen/pillow/setup.py", line 1024, in <module>
      zip_safe=not (debug_build() or PLATFORM_MINGW),
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 188, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 78, in run
      _build_ext.run(self)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-8v6p9cen/pillow/setup.py", line 790, in build_extensions
      raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException: jpeg
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-8v6p9cen/pillow/setup.py", line 1037, in <module>
      raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
  
  The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
  
  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
  
  
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pillow
  Running setup.py clean for pillow
Failed to build pillow
Installing collected packages: pillow, matplotlib
  Running setup.py install for pillow ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-8v6p9cen/pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-9716y_zm/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    running egg_info
    writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
    writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    
    
    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
    
    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/pip-install-8v6p9cen/pillow/setup.py", line 1024, in <module>
        zip_safe=not (debug_build() or PLATFORM_MINGW),
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 589, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 78, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-8v6p9cen/pillow/setup.py", line 790, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: jpeg
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-8v6p9cen/pillow/setup.py", line 1037, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
    
    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
    
    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
    
    
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-8v6p9cen/pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-9716y_zm/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-8v6p9cen/pillow/
```

so after some googling i found

```text
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install --upgrade pillow
```

then trying to run `sudo pip3 install matplotlib` again
i still receive the same error.

any help would be much appreciated. or an easier way to build this word cloud would work too.

thanks

cheers

Answer (score 50):

Try this:

```
apt-get install libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev
```

and then

```
pip3 install Pillow
```

also try updating setuptools:

```
sudo pip install -U setuptools
```

Answer (score 10):

**tl;dr** `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`

The problem I ran into was python module `Pillow` version 3.7 failing to compile during `python -m pip install Pillow`.

```
The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
```

(longer text)

```
Building wheels for collected packages: Pillow, pytest-dependency, yamllint, docopt
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Pillow ... error
  Complete output from command /tmp/project1/.venv-3.7.5-ubuntu-18.04/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-lsme78lo/Pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp7riogqqfpip-wheel- --python-tag cp37:
  /usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  running egg_info
  writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching '*.c'
  warning: no files found matching '*.h'
  warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
  writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext


  The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/pip-build-lsme78lo/Pillow/setup.py", line 1024, in <module>
      zip_safe=not (debug_build() or PLATFORM_MINGW),
    File /tmp/project1/.venv-3.7.5-ubuntu-18.04/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File /tmp/project1/.venv-3.7.5-ubuntu-18.04/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File /tmp/project1/.venv-3.7.5-ubuntu-18.04/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 78, in run
      _build_ext.run(self)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-lsme78lo/Pillow/setup.py", line 790, in build_extensions
      raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException: jpeg
```

The versions of `pip`, `setuptools`, and `wheel` were the default Ubuntu 18 apt-managed versions. These are old versions.

I updated `pip`, `setuptools`, and `wheel`.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

This updated `pip` to 21.3.1, `setuptools` to 60.5.0, `wheel` to 0.37.1.

The `pip install` of `Pillow` succeeded.

This occurred on Ubuntu 18 using python 3.7.5.

Answer (score 2):

Update pip,setuptools and wheel

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

Then re-run Pillow command

```
python -m pip install Pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

just try to install this specific version of pillow. **pip install Pillow==7.2.0**. it worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having troubles with this (and using vscode), check the version of Python your interpreter is using. My interpreter was using python 3.11 and I'd the error, I changed to python 3.9 and it worked.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the following error in my project, I hope it can be solved:

```bash
Building wheels for collected packages: matplotlib
  Building wheel for matplotlib (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [593 lines of output]

      Edit setup.cfg to change the build options; suppress output with --quiet.

      BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
        matplotlib: yes [3.3.2]
            python: yes [3.10.13 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Sep 11 2023,
                        13:24:38) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]]
          platform: yes [win32]
       sample_data: yes [installing]
             tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
            macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]

      E:\Program Files\miniconda3\envs\dbgpt_plugins\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py:80: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
              If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      E:\Program Files\miniconda3\envs\dbgpt_plugins\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:674: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The namespace_packages parameter is deprecated.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Please replace its usage with implicit namespaces (PEP 420).

              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html#keyword-namespace-packages for details.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)

.....

      UPDATING build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\matplotlib\_version.py
      set build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\matplotlib\_version.py to '3.3.2'
      running build_ext
      Extracting freetype-2.6.1.tar.gz
      Building freetype in build\freetype-2.6.1
      msbuild build\freetype-2.6.1\builds\windows\vc2010\freetype.sln /t:Clean;Build /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64
      error: command 'msbuild' failed: None
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for matplotlib
  Running setup.py clean for matplotlib
Failed to build matplotlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for matplotlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```